# Let $S$ be any non-empty subset of a group $G$. Does there exists a UNIQUE MAXIMAL subgroup $H$ such that $S$ is union of (some) left cosets of $H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, maximal-subgroup

It can be shown easily that there exists subgroup(s) such that $S$ is union of its left cosets. Trivial example: Take the trivial subgroup $H_0=\{e\}$ and then $S=\bigsqcup\limits_{g\in S}gH_0$.

Then I constructed a POSET,
$$X=\{H\subseteq G\mid H\text{ is subgroup and }S\text{ is union of left cosets of }H\},$$

order $X$ by $H\le H'\iff H\subseteq H'$. I was thinking to apply Zorn's lemma here. But I'm unable to prove the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma (the condition "union of left cosets" is creating problem).

Then I made some observations such that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $S=\bigsqcup\limits_{g\in I}gH$ where $I\subseteq G$ is indexing set. Then $I\subseteq S$ and $H\subseteq \bigcap\limits_{g\in I} g^{-1}S$.

This exercise is given under the section of Group Action, so I have tried to think using actions but got nothing useful.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: "The section" of what?

Comment: The title of your post  is very misleading. I think you mean "does there exist a unique subgroup $H$ of $G$ which is maximal with respect to property that $S$ is the union of some left cosets of $H$".

Comment: Yes I think so. This is exactly the statement of the question given.

Comment: But that's not what it says in the title of your post. The subgroup you are looking for is not (usually) a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us remark that for a subgroup $H$, we have $S = \cup_{g\in S}~ gH$ if, and only if :
$$HS = \{hg : h\in H, g\in S\} \subset S$$

Using this, it is not hard to show that the condition of Zorn's lemma are satisfies.

But we can actually construct the maximal subgroup explicitly, by considering the action of $G$ on itself on the left.

What we are actually looking for is the stabilizer of $S$ :
$$H_{\max} = \operatorname{Stab}(S) = \{ h\in G\mid hS\subset S\}$$

Let me know if you want me to fill in more details in some part of the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to complete the proof.

Comment: In the first remark will it be $HS$ or $SH$? If we consider union of left cosets?

Comment: It is $HS$ if you are considering left cosets.